# Не возвращается ответ из Ajax-запроса в Django

Tags: ajax, django

Тривиальная задача - динамически обеспечить набор значений поля `select` HTML-формы. Есть 2 поля HTML-формы, в первом набор значений формируется на сервере, а во втором поле значения `select`-oв зависят от результата установки значения в первом поле. Такая динамика традиционно организуется с помощью AJAX-запросов.

В данном случае Ajax-вызов берёт выбранное пользователем значение из первого поля и передаёт на сервер во `view`.

`View` успешно подхватывает вызов с переданным параметром и в ходе дальнейшей обработки обращается к методу модели `__str__` чтобы сформировать строку варианта `select`-а и, как обычно, по команде `return` должна вернуть это значение в вызывающее `view`, но фактически возврат происходит непонятно куда... Здесь работа сервера прекращается, т.е. он не реагирует на запросы и обновления страниц.

Отладочная консоль браузера сообщает, что произошла внутренняя ошибка сервера - 500.

При этом, вне Ajax-запросов указанный метод представления строки в модели работает корректно.

**AJAX-запрос:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i = 0;
    $("select#staff").change(function () {
        console.log('ajax-staffdep-' + i++);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "staff_deps/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { staff: +$(this).val() },
            success: function(j) {
                var options = '<option value="">******</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + parseInt(j[i]['id']) + '">' + j[i]['name'] + '</option>';
                }
                $("#staffdep").html(options);
                $("#staffdep option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
                $("#staffdep").attr('disabled', false);
                $("#staff").attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Veiw:**

```
def staff_deps(request):
    deps=[]
    if 'staff' in request.GET: 
        staffDeps = Staff.objects.filter(id=int(request.GET['staff']))[0].department.all()
        for staffdep in staffDeps: # было staffdeps
            deps.append({'id':staffdep.id, 'name': staffdep.depName})
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(deps))
```

**Метод модели `__str__`:**

```
 def __str__(self): # специализация сотрудника
        stritem = "{0}".format(self.get_depName_display())
        if self.quoteAvailable:
            stritem += " (квота: {0} из {1})".format(str(self.quote-self.quoteUsed), str(self.quote))
        return stritem
```

Обращение к методу `__str__` происходит в цикле `for staffdep in staffdeps`, там формирование строки `специализации сотрудника` с квотами идёт нормально, но после `return stritem` всё завершается неответом сервера на все остальные обращения.

Непонятно куда "ушёл" возврат значения `__str__`?

Такая же история происходит и применением Ajax-запроса JS-методом `getJSON`.

Что могло произойти в данном случае и как получить требуемые данные с ответом сервера?

Comment: `$("#staff").attr('selected', 'selected');` - ??

Comment: Убрал опечатку, но она никоим образом не влияет на ход описанных событий!

Comment: Ошибку надо смотреть в логах сервера, а не консоли браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку во view. В заголовке цикла не та переменная (опечатка). Но здесь Django не дал ошибок в традиционном оформлении, а в консоли сервера отобразил, что имя "staffdeps" не существует. Действительное имя должно быть "staffDeps". Всех благодарю за участие!